# Using params instead of bearer token in API call in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am using a lot of API's in my React Native app. In a lot of places i'm using bearer token for different purposes. Right now it looks like:

```js
 getCustomerProfile: async token => {
  return await fetch(
   `MY API`,
   {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
     Accept: 'application/json',
     Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
     'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
   }
  )
   .then(response => response.json())
   .then(json => {
    return json;
   })
   .catch(error => warn(error));
 },
```

But now i don't want to use headers and just want to use params for getting response. In postman my API works fine with params. But how can i change here to get response using params instead of headers?

Answer (score 2):

The `fetch` standard in their [documentation](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#fetch-api), suggests a way for using query params in fetch requests. So all you need to do **is to create a param and append it to your URL with `searchParams`** and then make your requestion as usual [`GET` request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

Here it is:

```js
var url = new URL("https://geo.example.org/api"),
    params = {lat:35.696233, long:139.570431}
Object.keys(params).forEach(key => url.searchParams.append(key, params[key]))
fetch(url).then(/* … */)
```

**NOTE:** You can also follow [this thread](https://github.com/github/fetch/issues/256) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

here is the exapmle code

```
fetch('your url', 
              {
              method: 'POST',
              headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',         
              },
              body: JSON.stringify(
              {
            "p1": "value1",
            "p2"  :  "value2",
              })
            }).then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
              // remaining code here 

            }).catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
                });
```

**ALternatively**  from official side

```
fetch('https://mywebsite.com/endpoint/', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    firstParam: 'yourValue',
    secondParam: 'yourOtherValue'
  })
});
```